# Asking for a Qt colorbar control & a chart control

Tags: qt, qt4, colorbar

**color bar and line chart**

[image]

I would like to create or leverage two Qt controls like these above.

One is a colorbar with pinches on it.

The other is a chart with points on the line, while we can drag & drop the points on the line and the alpha values of the points can be fetched.

Can any one let me know what's the name of those controls? I would like search them on line first, but I need to know what key words to search.

Or if there's existing controls, or any one can share the code, can you pls let me know? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

QWT seems to have charts, without dragable points http://qwt.sourceforge.net/curvescreenshots.html

[image: Example for a plotted graph]

Answer (score 0):

Come on - this screenshot is from an Qwt example called eventfilter that explicitly shows how dragging of points could be implemented.

In SVN trunk you find another example called itemeditor that shows how to drag/drop shape items on the plot canvas.

Note that Qwt is a Qt/C++ plot framework, that can be customized/extended to almost everything what makes sense to do on a coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that there are precise terms for controls like this. I think "color picker" and "line chart" are your best bets.

[qt-app.org](http://qt-apps.org/) is probably the best place I know of to look for custom controls.